# Reading many (1000+) files with dlmread - Loop with varying filenames?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vector, vtk

I'm very new to matlab, or coding for that matter.

I'm running a simulation which outputs thousands of files. These files are .vtk and are read correctly by dlmread.

I tried reading one of them, defining it as a matrix and extracting column vectors out of this matrix. This works fine. What i need now is to not only read one of them, but all. The filenames vary by a number, for example cover1000.vtk, cover2000.vtk, ...., cover1200000.vtk.

I want all of them to be read with dlmread and stored as a different matrix. How do i do that? Here is what i have right now, working with one file at a time:

```
A_1000 = dlmread ('cover1000.vtk') %matrix a containing values from vtk file_in_loadpath

fx_1000 = A(1:20,1) %extracting vector with specific values

fx_ave_1000 = sum(fx_1000)/length(fx_1000) % average of the values in extracted vector
```

I'm thinking of a loop, but how do i create a loop with varying file names? 
Also I've read that a loop is not the best idea, cell arrays would be better. But i have absolutely no idea how to implement any of this.

Thanks for your help!
cheers

Comment: are all your files stored in one directory?

Comment: Yes they are. Their name only varies by the number, for example cover1000.vtk, cover2000.vtk...
The difference between the numbers is usually 1000 and is constant through all files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the function `dir` to list all the vtk files in your directory then loop over those files.

```
filename = dir('*.vtk'); %list all the vtk files in your current directory.

for ii = 1:length(filename)
A = dlmread (filename(ii).name) %matrix a containing values from vtk file_in_loadpath
fx{ii} = A(1:20,1) %extracting vector with specific value
fx_ave{ii} = sum(fx{ii})/length(fx{ii}) % average of the values in extracted vector
end
```

The results are now stored in two cells: `fx` and `fx_ave`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This works. Only thing left for me is to find out how to access values from fx_ave, but that should be possible with the documentation on cell arrays.

Comment: You welcome, simply write: `fx_ave{1}` to access data of file `filename(1).name`. `fx_ave{2}` to access data of file `filename(2).name`...

Comment: Thanks! But somehow there is an error. If i extract a vector fx{550} for example, i don't geht the correct values, the are off by a little bit. I tried looking into the files 549, 550, 551 but in none of them the values appear that matlab shows. I don't know where the mistake could be, as fx is not averaging any values, it should show what i see in the files.

Comment: @matejmarti the files are not necessarily going to be read in numerical order. Look at the output of `dir` to see the order of the files.

Comment: thanks @excaza, that could be it! i'll look into that!

Comment: @matejmarti, given the input filename you described, I suspect it is exactly what excasa mention. The files are processed in a different order than you'd want. Read this question and the answer to see how to handle that part and reorder them properly: [How to preserve the order of filename?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58804961/3460361)